# RESTful API using OAuth where authentication tokens are sent as part of the HTTP request

Tags: python, api, rest, oauth

I am pretty new to developing APIs. This is part of my class project and the goal is to create a RESTful API in python where the delegation is done via OAuth and these tokens should be sent as part of the HTTP request.

I was advised that I should create an API that involves delegating the OAuth model into a proxy-like approach where authentication tokens are sent as part of the HTTP request. What exactly does a proxy-like approach mean? Any ideas?

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me out with this and also on how to create an API (even if it is not python specific, I can take cue from that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new to REST services, then [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21174/Everything-About-REST-Web-Services-What-and-How-Pa) will be nice kick start for you. 
You can find [here](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask) how to develop a basic rest api in python and the same [with authentication](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/restful-authentication-with-flask).

So what is OAuth?

OAuth can be many things. It is most commonly used to allow an application (the consumer) to access data or services that the user (the resource owner) has with another service (the provider), and this is done in a way that prevents the consumer from knowing the login credentials that the user has with the provider.

For example, consider a website or application that asks you for permission to access your Facebook account and post something to your timeline. In this example you are the resource holder (you own your Facebook timeline), the third party application is the consumer and Facebook is the provider. Even if you grant access and the consumer application writes to your timeline, it never sees your Facebook login information.

This usage of OAuth does not apply to a client/server RESTful API. Something like this would only make sense if your RESTful API can be accessed by third party applications (consumers).

In the case of a direct client/server communication there is no need to hide login credentials, the client (curl in the examples above) receives the credentials from the user and uses them to authenticate requests with the server directly.

Comment: Thanks Selva. That helps a lot. I have to use OAuth since third party applications request data. Let me delve into more details. So I have a mobile app that will retrieve health data items from a EHR system. The goal is to build a web service that would take HTTP requests and the serve whatever is wanted from that data in a Electronic Health Record (EHR)

Comment: This link (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth) provides the way on how you can get the data through  signup with google. The steps would be the same for others like facebook, twitter except some minor changes. Is this you want or i miss understood?